# How to automatically render submenu block in sidebar?

Tags: views, 8, navigation

I want to automatically render a submenu in a block placed in sidebar (Drupal 8). This submenu could be one of those I setup in Main Navigation menu but could also be one of other custom-made menus.

What I have done by now is:

1. Create a new independent menu either replicating each of Main Navigation submenus or for each of my custom-made menus.

   2. Place one block per menu/submenu in sidebar.
   3. Make them visible/invisible according `Visibility -> Pages`.

Placing Main Navigation block also in sidebar is a no-go as it shows all equal-level menu entries.

I suspect this could be done in a more efficient way using views but I haven't figured out how.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could create one menu and then use the menu block module to spit out the submenus based on the active menu trail.  https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Menu Block module allows to avoid recreating the submenus by cloning & filtering Main Navigation but the issue remains the same: I'm forced to place one additional block per submenu.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I don't follow.  But the point of the menu block module is to display a submenu based on the active menu.  It should all be dynamic.  Make sure you have a menu block created that displays based on the active trail, depth 2... etc.  Play around with the options so you get familiar with how to set it up.